Weird behavior when fetching an array from a server [Typescript]
I am trying to fetch an array from a server, in particular this is what I do in the backend:
this.app.get('/list', asyncHandler(async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
    
    const validPuzzles: Array<string> = await fs.readdir('./puzzles');

    response
        .status(StatusCodes.OK)
        .send(validPuzzles);
}));

Now, in the client side, I am trying to fetch and utilize it as an object.
const validPuzzles =  <Array<string>> JSON.parse(await (await fetch('http://localhost:8789/list')).text());

And this works!
However, what I really want to do is:
const puzzleData = await fetch('http://localhost:8789/list');
// (See EDIT, I actually also have a console log here)
const validPuzzles = <Array<string>> JSON.parse(await puzzleData.text());

Which throws me the weird error "TypeError: Body is unusable" - it is really weird since doing all in one line works, but dividing it into another variable breaks it!
EDIT: Turns out that I have a console.log that is breaking it!
In essence, what I actually have is:
const puzzleData = await fetch('http://localhost:8789/list');
console.log(await puzzleData.text());
const validPuzzles = <Array<string>> JSON.parse(await puzzleData.text());

Which throws the "TypeError: Body is unusable"; however, if I comment the console log:
const puzzleData = await fetch('http://localhost:8789/list');
// console.log(await puzzleData.text());
const validPuzzles = <Array<string>> JSON.parse(await puzzleData.text());

This works!
Why does this happen? I would have never expected a console log to break my code!

And this works! Im pretty sure it doesn't as it doesn't have matching braces.

@tkausl oops typo while copy pasting, fixed!

@Blackhole puzzleData is already awaited from the fetch. puzzleData.text() does indeed return a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/text

Because you await it twice?
